# Как результат функции data_driven_time_warp превратить в обычный вектор

Tags: r

`data_driven_time_warp` - *(dtw)*  это динамическое искривление временной шкалы. В функцию подается обычный вектор, на выходе функция уже выдает  две координаты *x* и *у* - время(синтетическое) и значения(вектора).

```
data_driven_time_warp <- function (y) {
cbind(  x = cumsum(c(0, abs(diff(y)))),y = y)
}
y <- cumsum(rnorm(200))+1000  # some data

i <- seq(1,length(y),by=10)
op <- par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar=c(.1,.1,.1,.1))

plot(y, type="l", axes = FALSE)
abline(v=i, col="grey")
lines(y, lwd=3)
box()
d <- data_driven_time_warp(y)
plot(d, type="l", axes=FALSE)
abline(v=d[i,1], col="grey")
lines(d, lwd=3)
box()
par(op)
```

подаем обычный вектор в функцию

```
> head(y)
[1] 999.9084 999.1956 999.8033 999.2182 998.6474 997.0736
```

на выходе получаем матрицу

```
> head(d)
             x        y
[1,] 0.0000000 999.9084
[2,] 0.7128334 999.1956
[3,] 1.3205700 999.8033
[4,] 1.9056173 999.2182
[5,] 2.4764494 998.6474
[6,] 4.0502315 997.0736
```

на картинке вверху ряд до преобразования, внизу после
[image: на картинке вверху ряд до преобразования, внизу после]

Вопрос как мне эту матрицу "d" преобразовать в обычный вектор но что бы он был такой же как на картинке внизу

Comment: `y` в матрице `d` - это и есть исходный `y`. То есть он уже "такой же". На картинке вверху график от одной переменной, соответственно все точки имеют равное расстояние между собой по оси абсцисс. На второй картинке график строится по двум координатам.

Comment: ну так вопрос как раз в том как из матрицы d сделать вектор что бы он выглядел так как на картинке 2, то есть мне не нужен исходный у

Comment: Еще раз: никакого не-исходного вектора `y` нет. Функция `data_driven_time_warp` ничего с исходным вектором `y` не делает, а создает еще один вектор `x`. Дальше рисуется зависимость `y` от `x`. То есть нельзя сказать, что на второй картинке "изображен вектор" - там изображена зависимость одной переменной от другой.

Comment: Я вас понимаю, я и не говорил что на второй картинке вектор я говорил что хотел бы получить вектор что бы он выглядел как на картинке 2, можно ли какими то хитрыми молитвами это сделать?

Comment: Тогда единственное, что приходит на ум, это построить модель зависимости `d$y` от `d$x` - сплайны какие-нибудь или loess. Затем предсказать `y` в точках 1, 2. 3... до `length(x)`. Так получится некоторое приближение искомой картинки.

Comment: можете показать кодом пример со сплайнами? был бы мега благодарен

Comment: Я попробовал пока что с loess: `fit <- loess(d$y ~ d$x, span = 0.03)` `preds  <- predict(fit, 1:200)` `plot(preds, type="l", axes=FALSE)`

Comment: получилось что то типа обычного сглаживания)

Comment: а как сделать со сплайнами можете показать,я попробовал сделать сам но что выдает ошибку когда predict делаю,  я просто никогда такими вещами не занимался